# 2d Platform (smooth) collision less CPU intensive

Tags: java, cpu, collision

I am trying to make a 2D platformer game. I have the collision detection working, although it is very CPU intensive. I have all my levels stored in a String array, and all of my actual Game Objects in an ArrayList. I look through the entire ArrayList (every frame) and do my collision detection accordingly. Here is the code for my collision detection as it now stands:

```
isFalling = true;
    canMoveLeft = true;
    canMoveRight = true;
    colRect.x = this.x - 5;
    colRect.y = this.y - 5;

    for (int i = 0; i < gameObjects.size(); i++) {
        if (gameObjects.get(i).levelNum == levelIndex)
            if (checkCollision(colRect, gameObjects.get(i)))

                if (gameObjects.get(i).type == "brick") {
                if (!pixelFree(centerX(), y + height, gameObjects.get(i)) ||
                    !pixelFree(x + 1, y + height, gameObjects.get(i)) ||
                    !pixelFree(x + width - 2, y + height, gameObjects.get(i))) {
                    isFalling = false;
                    gameObjects.get(i).move();
                }

                if (!pixelFree(x + width, centerY(), gameObjects.get(i)) ||
                    !pixelFree(x + width, y + 1, gameObjects.get(i)) ||
                    !pixelFree(x + width, y + height - 2, gameObjects.get(i))) {
                    canMoveRight = false;
                }

                if (!pixelFree(x - 1, centerY(), gameObjects.get(i)) ||
                    !pixelFree(x - 1, y + 1, gameObjects.get(i)) ||
                    !pixelFree(x - 1, y + height - 2, gameObjects.get(i))) {
                    canMoveLeft = false;
                }

                if (!pixelFree(x + 1, y - 3, gameObjects.get(i)) ||
                    !pixelFree(centerX(), y - 3, gameObjects.get(i)) ||
                    !pixelFree(x + width - 1, y - 3, gameObjects.get(i))) {
                    if (!pixelFree(centerX(), y + height, gameObjects.get(i))) {
                        die();
                    }
                    if (dy < 0) {
                        dy *= -1;
                    }
                }
                if (checkCollision(this, gameObjects.get(i))) {
                    int horizontalDist = (pow(this.centerX() - gameObjects.get(i).centerX(), 2));
                    int verticalDist = (pow(this.centerY() - gameObjects.get(i).centerY(), 2));
                    if (horizontalDist <= verticalDist) {
                        if (this.centerY() <= gameObjects.get(i).centerY()) {



                            y = gameObjects.get(i).y - height - 1;
                        }

                    } else {
                        if (this.centerX() <= gameObjects.get(i).centerX()) {
                            x = gameObjects.get(i).x - width - 1;
                        } else {
                            canMoveLeft = false;
                            x = gameObjects.get(i).x + gameObjects.get(i).width + 1;

                        }

                    }

                }
            } else if (gameObjects.get(i).type == "finisher") {
            if (checkCollision(this, gameObjects.get(i))) {
                if (coinsCaptured == totalCoinsInLevel)
                    finishLevel();
            }
        } else if (gameObjects.get(i).type == "spike") {
            if (checkCollision(this, gameObjects.get(i))) {
                die();
            }

        } else if (gameObjects.get(i).type == "coin") {
            if (checkCollision(this, gameObjects.get(i))) {
                gameObjects.get(i).take();
            }

        }
    }
```

Now, as you can see, this is very CPU intensive. Does anyone have any ideas of a more CPU-friendly method of collision detection? Keep in mind that I have moving GameObjects as well as static ones.

Comment: What does checkCollision() look like?  How about pixelFree?

Comment: Checkcollision() simply is an A ABBA bounding box collision detection function, and pixelFree determines if a given point is inside a given gameObject

Comment: I have a feeling that the Cpu intensive behavior is due to the fact that I'm looping through hundreds of objects in an arraylist

Comment: You may get a little speedup by using an array.  Also, I would try running a profiler such as Visual VM to see which methods are taking the most time.

Comment: That's a good idea. I'm pretty sure the main cause is pixelFree,  which sees if a given pixel collides with a given game object. It would be helpful if I knew how to only loop through objects a certain distance away from the player

Comment: Or, an efficient way to determine if a point collides with any game object